# How to let Enum conform to Hashable when Case is having Optional Protocol Type as an Associated Type?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, functional-programming, protocols

**Context**

I have an `Enum` where one of its `Cases` has an `Optional Protocol Type` as one of its `Associated Types`. Since adding this new `Associated Type`, I get the following `Compiler Error`:

> **Compiler Error #1:** Type 'MyEnum' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

> **Compiler Error #2:** Type 'MyEnum' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Component { ... }

enum MyEnum: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int { hashValue }

    case myCase1
    case myCase2(value: Int? = nil)
    case myCase3(component: (any Component)? = nil) // Adding this Case breaks the Code.
}
```

---

**Question**

How can I solve the `Compiler Errors` above and support an `Optional Protocol Type` as an `Associated Type` for an `Enum Case`?

Comment: @Sweeper No, `Component` has a few `Type Requirements`, but since they are not used in this example, I left them out for clarity.

Comment: Note that `any Component` does not conform to `Hashable`, even if you say `protocol Component: Hashable`. [Protocols do not conform to other protocols,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/5133585) especially those that have type requirements. See the link for why what you are trying to do does not make sense.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for your answer. Does this mean, it is impossible to use a `Protocol Type` as an `Associated Type` for an `Enum Case` in `Swift`? There must be a workaround?

Comment: It is possible if your protocol doesn't have type requirements. It does not *make sense* to do so, for the reasons mentioned in the link.